# Display Attributes in User Properties in Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, ldif

Is it possible to display the hidden attribute, EmployeeID or EmployeeNumber under the General Tab in a user's Active Directory Account? If so, how.....

Answer (score 0):

You can add these attributes adding display columns see [Modifying Existing User Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677291.aspx). This article explain how to modify DisplaySpecifiers.

Be carefull read [this KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/884402/en-us) that explain that modifying '`defaul_dsiplay`' is not enough, you had to copy all the contents of '`extraColumns`' attribute and add your ones to the '`organizationalUnit-Display`' object.

You'd better do this using LDIF file and LDIFDE.EXE.

Comment: I mean, under the user's profile. Can I add a field that displays Emplyee Number when I double click on the user's profile page?